# how to use firestore query result in another query. Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

Tell me please. Here is the base:
"orders" inside this base there are fields ID, number, address, and so on and there is a collection of "carpets" inside the base of carpets there are also different fields, including the field cost (that is, the cost of cleaning this carpet).
now QUESTION:
how to calculate the total cost and write the result in the "orders" database field?

in general it is interesting how to implement it. How to make such queries so that later the result obtained is already written in a different field?

Comment: Instead of describing how your database looks like, please edit your question and add a screenshot of it. Please also show us what you have tried so far in code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good approach for a summary field is to define a property on the parent document ("order", in the OP case) and code a write-trigger on the child collection ("order/carpets").

The trigger's job is to determine what sort of write has taken place on the collection and update the parent doc's prop accordingly.

Code something like (*very roughly like*) the following in your cloud functions folder...

```
// when carpets are written, update their parent order's "ordersTotal" prop 
exports.didUpdateCarpets = functions.firestore.document('orders/{orderId}/carpets').onWrite(async (change, context) => {
  const ref = db.collection('orders').doc(orderId);
  try {
    await runTransaction(db, async (transaction) => {
      const doc = await transaction.get(ref);
      let ordersTotal = doc.data().ordersTotal;

      // modify orderTotal based on the trigger params
      const before = change.before.exists ? change.before.data() : null;
      const after = change.after.exists ? change.after.data() : null;

      if (!before) ordersTotal += after.cost;         // created
      else if (!after) ordersTotal -= before.cost;    // deleted
      else ordersTotal += after.cost - before.cost;   // modified
    
      transaction.update(ref, { ordersTotal });
    });
  } catch (e) {
    console.log("Transaction failed: ", e);
  }
});
```